# How can I send parameters to methods using Maven/testng?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cmd, testng

How can I send parameters to methods via the console?

I have a method that looks like this:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    botClass.Desktop(driver, "same url");       
}
```

I want to send a `String` URL parameter through the console.

For example, I want to be able to type `mvn clean test, www.google.com` in the console, and the program should connect to Google and perform the test.
Is this possible? If yes, please give me some advice on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

**1)** in your scr/test/resouces place a testConfig.properties:

```
url = ${url}
```

**2)** write the test:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception{

        String urlParam = null;

        try {

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream input = null;
            input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testConfig.properties");

            prop.load(input);

            urlParam = prop.getProperty("url");

        }catch (Exception e){}

        // use urkParam
    }
```

**3)** in your pom.xml add this:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
```

**4)** run maven as follows:

```
mvn clean test resources:testResources -Durl=www.google.com
```

Now you will get parameterized url based on maven param.

Comment: receive a error when i try to run the test 
[link](http://www.interload.co.il/upload/5985310.png)

Comment: ok place your test method and mvn command.. and your properties file content

Comment: Any luck with testing? This works for sure you probably missed some small detail

Comment: i found a easier way to resolve it without change nothing in the form file.

thanks you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

i found a easier way to resolve it without change nothing in the porm file. i wrote in my class `String valueFromMaven=System.getProperty("URL");` and in the console i start the test with `mvn clean test -DURL=www.google.com` .